# ValueError: Specified a sep and a delimiter; you can only specify one. roster = pd.read_csv(filepath,converters,usecols,index_col=“NetID”)

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, data-analysis, file-handling

```
filepath = “C:/Users/Kunwar Rajeev Singh/Desktop/DAILY PROJECTS/My Python projects/School Grading Pandas Practice/data/roster.csv”

converters = {“NetID”:str.lower,“Email Address”:str.lower}
usecols = [“NetID”,“Name”,“Email Address”]

roster = pd.read_csv(filepath,converters,usecols,index_col=“NetID”)

ValueError: Specified a sep and a delimiter; you can only specify one.
```

I was using converters and usecols with read_csv method
I know I am using sep and delimeter on the same go but can someone guide how I can rectify this error??
I know i can use the coverters and usecols separately but still wanted to know if there is any other way i can use them together and successfully run the code

I was using converters and usecols with read_csv method
I know I am using sep and delimeter on the same go but can someone guide how I can rectify this error??
I know i can use the coverters and usecols separately but still wanted to know if there is any other way i can use them together and successfully run the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be in the way you are passing converters and usecols as arguments. Based on the syntax specified in documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html there should be name of the argument and its value.

```
roster = pd.read_csv(filepath, converters=converters, usecols=usecols,index_col=“NetID”)
```